# How to remove null or empty list from an "unmodifiable" map

Tags: java, java-8

I have an unmodifiable map (`Map<String, Object>`). This contains a key-value pair, where the value should be a List, but for a specific key the value is an empty List.

How can I remove that empty list from the map and return?

I have done it using predicate which checks if the value is an instance of collection and then check if Collections.isNotEmpty(..).

I want to know is there any better approach than this? (In Java 8)

```
public class StudentTest {

    Predicate<Object> isCollectionNotEmpty = input -> {
        if (input instanceof Collection) {
            return CommonCollectionUtils.isNotEmpty((Collection<?>)input);
        }
        return true;
    };
    Predicate<Object> isObjectNotNull = input -> Objects.nonNull(input);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentTest s = new StudentTest();
        final Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("student_batch_size", 200);
        map1.put("student_avg_height", 172);
        map1.put("Student_names", Collections.emptyList());

        final Map<String, Object> finalMap = s.getFinalMap(Collections.unmodifiableMap(map1));

        System.out.println(finalMap);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getFinalMap(final Map<String, Object> inputMap) {
        final Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        //inputMap.values().remove(Collections.emptyList());
        resultMap.putAll(inputMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> isObjectNotNull.and(isCollectionNotEmpty).test(entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue())));
        return resultMap;
    }

}
```

Expected Output:

```
{student_avg_height=172, student_batch_size=200}
```

Comment: You can do away with the second `Predicate` and just return `false` if the `instanceof` check fails

Comment: Can you please elaborate. In case its an empty list, the `instanceof` should return true.

Comment: Yes, but [`null instanceof <Anything>` will always be `false`](http://ideone.com/2BbyRl).

Comment: The use of a `putAll` is just _odd_. `collect` directly `toMap` - all you're doing is adding unnecessary cognitive load and creating unnecessary objects (the intermediate `Map`).

Comment: Thanks @Boris. I am using `putAll` for a new map.  And inside it I have collected using  `Collectors.toMap(...)`. Are you saying I should not use the `putAll` at all and directly return the map ?

Comment: Yes - `return inputMap.entrySet()...collect(toMap(...))`. You save some redundant code and a `Map` creation.

Comment: Thanks @Boris the Spider for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) might be a good option to consider.

```
private Map<String, Object> getFinalMap(final Map<String, Object> inputMap) {
    final Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>(inputMap);
    resultMap.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection) e.getValue()).isEmpty());

    return resultMap;
}
```

If a stream-based approach is more appealing to you

```
private Map<String, Object> getFinalMap(final Map<String, Object> inputMap) {
    return inputMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> !(e.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection) e.getValue()).isEmpty()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

---

UPDATE

If you want to filter out null objects regardless of their type, here are slight changes to the methods mentioned above

1) removeIf

```
resultMap.entrySet()
    .removeIf(e -> Objects.isNull(e.getValue()) || 
                   (e.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection) e.getValue()).isEmpty());
```

2) stream-based

```
.filter(e -> Objects.nonNull(e.getValue()))
.filter(e -> !(e.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection) e.getValue()).isEmpty()))
```

Comment: OP wants to check null object too.

Comment: Yes, both looks fine to me. What about the Objects.isNonNull()?  Does the `instacneof` checks the nullity ?

Comment: @HadiJ `.removeIf(e -> Objects.isNull(e.getValue()) || e.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection) e.getValue()).isEmpty())`

Comment: Yes, I can certainly add an extra filter. So using a predicate function directly in code is a bad idea? Just curious.

Comment: @RoyalTiger it doesn't, but if it's not a Collection, it won't be filtered out. So a condition `Objects.isNull(e.getValue())` is required...

Comment: @RoyalTiger we use `instanceof` primarily to do a cast in the second part of the expression. I wanted to separate two conditions (a null object of any type and an empty collection)

Comment: @RoyalTiger *(I am talking about predicates as fields)* it's not bad, but it's not particularly useful when a condition is as simple as `Objects.nonNull(input)` (which could be `Objects::notNull`, btw)

Comment: @RoyalTiger I can think of a project where predicates are used a lot and form various composite predicates. It would reasonable to generalise them, move to a constants class and name accordingly (e.g. `IS_COLLECTION_EMPTY`).

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko : Yes, actually I wanted to use predicate so that I can use from multiple places. You are right to add a common class and move all the predicates to it. It's a nice idea. So if there is a scenario like this we can use predicates. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach of using `Object` as a value in the `Map` is questionable. You don't fully control type safety. I'd consider replacing the student `Map` with an object reflecting single student batch properties.

```
class StudentBatch {
   int size;
   int avgHeight;
   Collection<String> names;

   boolean hasValidNames() {
       return names != null && !names.isEmpty();
   }
}
```

As you see I've put the `hasValidNames` predicate to the object which makes it reusable and allows to simplify the condition you're trying to optimize.

```
  List<StudentBatch> batchList = new ArrayList<>();
  batchList.stream().filter(StudentBatch::hasValidNames).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Right, but the problem is this Map is coming REST POST request. Its a Json which is being converted into a Map<String, Object>. This json can contain anything like below:

{  
   "student_batch_size":200,
   "student_avg_height":170,
   "Student_names":[  
      "Ryan",
      "Nick",
      "Balbowisky"
   ]
}

Comment: Ok. I get it. You can pretty easily map json document to an object. Most json parsers incl. Gson and Jackson support that. Maybe this could work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` checks the no nullity too, so no need to make it explicitly and you don't need to create a new `HashMap` even if the Map that you stream is not modifiable as the stream doesn't modify it directly but creates a new Map :

```
final Map<String, Object> finalMap =
     map
    .entry()
    .stream()
    .filter(e-> !isEmptyCollection(e))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue);


public void boolean isEmptyCollection(Entry<String, Object> entry){     
    return entry.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection<?>) entry.getValue()).isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: No need to `isEmptyCollection` and it could be like this `...filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Collection && ((Collection<?>) entry.getValue()).isEmpty())...` also OP wants to check null objects too. `isObjectNotNull`

Comment: @Boris the spider : I suppose that you propose a ternary. When it is long, it is not necessarily easy to read.

Comment: @Hadi J No need ? It is a readability question. And the filter that you give is incorrect since we want to keep the reverse. We should surround the whole expression with a negation operator.  Not very readable either. About the not null, that is not required thanks to `instanceof` that checks that